# Linq conditional select with null member collection

Tags: c#, linq

I have searched through a lot of similar questions, but cannot find one that solves this problem.  Good chance I am overlooking something obvious, but please suggest how to do this with a single iteration.

```
var dataWithResults =
    from d in data
    where d.QCResults != null
    from q in d.QCResults
    select new QCAMaterial
    {
        Name = q == null ? nodata : q.ComponentName,
        Value = q == null ? nodata : q.Result
    };

var dataWithNullResults =
    from d in data
    where d.QCResults == null
    select new QCAMaterial
    {
        Name = nodata,
        Value = nodata
    };
```

Comment: "but cannot find one that solves this problem." would you care to describe "this" problem? you did not even ask a question in your "question"

Comment: Are you using an ORM for this? Namely, do  you want a query like this to be successfully converted to Entity Framework SQL (with optionally nullable navigation collection)?

Comment: The rephrase as question:  How can this be done with a single iteration?  My example iterates through the data collection twice.  I am reviewing the current set of answers.  Thank you all for the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do a combination of `Enumerable.Empty` and `Enumerable.DefaultIfEmpty`:

```
var allData =
            from d in data
            from q in d.QCResults ?? Enumerable.Empty<QCResult>().DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new QCAMaterial
            {
                Name = q == null ? nodata : q.ComponentName,
                Value = q == null ? nodata : q.Result
            };
```

In case you want to treat an empty list (`QCResults`) the same as a `null` list, you can modify the query:

```
var allData =
            from d in data
            from q in (d.QCResults ?? Enumerable.Empty<QCResult>()).DefaultIfEmpty()
            select new QCAMaterial
            {
                Name = q == null ? nodata : q.ComponentName,
                Value = q == null ? nodata : q.Result
            };
```

Comment: The obvious thing I was missing is use of the ?? operator.  Need to keep it in mind.  Nice solution, easy to read.  I used the second option.  Thank You.

Comment: You could also use `??` further with `Name = q.ComponentName ?? nodata,`

Comment: @ColinM: No you couldn't. If q is `null` this will cause a `NullReferenceException`.

Comment: Correct, missed that part. `Name = q?.ComponentName ?? nodata,`

Answer (score 0):

Since both the classes without `QCResults` as well as `QCResults` with no specific data in their properties get the `nodata` value, you could omit the 'where' and combine them as:

```
    IEnumerable<QCResult> dummycol = new[] {new QCResult()}; //assuming QCResult is the class exposed by the QCResults property
    var res = from d in data                
            from q in d.QCResults ?? dummycol
            select new QCAMaterial
            {
                Name = q == null ? nodata: q.ComponentName, //side note: can also be written as q?.ComponentName ?? nodata
                Value = q == null ? nodata : q.Result
            };
```

If QCResults is empty, a dummy collection is used with a single entry.
The dummy-collection could be created inline as well, but this should be more efficient.

Comment: Nice solution also, but I prefer Sefe's which does not introduce new variables.  Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SelectMany:

```
    var result = data.SelectMany(d => 
                        {
                            return d.QCResults != null
                                ? d.QCResults.Select(q => new QCAMaterial { Name = q.ComponentName, Value = q.Result})
                                : new List<QCAMaterial>{new QCAMaterial { Name = "no data", Value = "no data" }};
                        });
```

Comment: Will use this to better understand SelectMany, but will not choose as the answer.  Probably works, but the QCAMaterial has more properties than shown, and I prefer solutions that list the projection once.  Thank You.